# passing custom class to parametrizedthreadstart class from main method

Tags: c#, multithreading, visual-studio-2010

I have this problem that i want to pass two custom class named Team to my Permeterized thread start class with my object class but can't how can i solve this problem here's my code

```
    public  void Game_Start(object starttime,Team _away,Team _home)
    {
        string text;
        DateTime StartTime = (DateTime)starttime;
        Console.WriteLine("Game Starts!");
        Show_Left(StartTime);
        text = Console.ReadLine();
        OnGoal += game_OnGoal;
        if (text == "Goal Away") OnGoal.Invoke(_away);
        if (text == "Goal Home") OnGoal.Invoke(_home);
    }
```

that i cant pass _away and _home parameters and my main method:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var away = new Team();
        var home = new Team();
        var counter = new Counter();
        Thread work = new Thread(counter.Game_Start);
        Timer timer = new Timer(counter.Times_up, work, 5400000, Timeout.Infinite);
        DateTime StartTime = DateTime.Now;
        work.Start(StartTime);
        work.Join();
        Console.Write("End");
        counter.Show_Left(StartTime);
        timer.Dispose();
        Console.Read();
    }
```

so how can i pass the two teams from main into my class what should i change?

Comment: Well which teams would you want to pass?

Comment: @JonSkeet both teams away and home

Comment: Do you mean the fields you've got somewhere, but haven't shown us? You haven't given us enough context.

Comment: @JonSkeet i edited the context i want away and home in my count.Game_Start method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass a single wrapper class instead:

```
public class Teams
{
  public Teams(Team home, Team away)
  {
     Home = home;
     Away = away;
  }

  public Team Home { get; private set; }

  public Team Away { get; private set; }
}
```

Comment: i want to pass two team objects in counter.Game_Start method from main method.

Comment: @rNuǝɹɐ - And writing a wrapper class that holds these two teams and using that instead is not an option, why?

Answer (score 2):

Use a lambda experssion:

```
Thread.Start(()=>Game_Start(starttime, home, away));
```

Note: This is technically the same as @Oded suggested, only the wrapper class is created by the compiler - as the closure.

Comment: Oh, I forgot it's possible to start a thread without the state parameter, so no need for that. I'll edit.